# How to select one checkbox at a time without using radio buttons in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to keep 2 checkboxes and only one should be selected at a time.How should I achieve my functionality in angularjs?

I have to use checkboxes only not radio buttons.

Comment: be strong with input type basics before coding

Comment: With radio buttons at least 1 must be selected both can't unselect.

Comment: Add a third radio for "N/A"

Comment: I get the answer on http://jsfiddle.net/m3jK7/2/

Answer (score 0):

If I am write like this in my code then it works Am I right or not?

```
`<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
  <label class="checkbox-inline col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsAnniversary" ng-model="Settings.IsAnniversaryMessages" value="true" ng-change="Settings.IsAnniversaryCoupon = false" checked="">Send messages
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsAnniversary" ng-model="Settings.IsAnniversaryCoupon" value="true" ng-change="Settings.IsAnniversaryMessages = false">Send coupons
  </label>
</div>`
```